# For a student, what is the optimal usage of a solution manual?

Tags: coursework, books

During coursework if a solution manual is available for the textbook, it is always a huge bonus for the student. While the student is exposed to a variety of relevant applications and tricks in the problems, the solution manual ensures the student's hard work spent trying out the problems does not go waste. The solution manual's availability is akin to the presence of a "Cheat" button in [crossword applets](http://www.guardian.co.uk/crosswords/cryptic/25671) - the earlier you press the less you try, but still the presence of the button is useful as such.

What are some useful tips for a student who wants to utilise the solution manual optimally?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Never use the solution manual before trying everything else; talk to friends, visit the professor, go to class and listen (!), check the internet. Once you use the solution manual for a problem, the potential gain from that problem is significantly and irrecoverably reduced.
2. Use the solution manual to check your work. (Duh.)
3. For problems you aren't planning on solving, you can use the solutions manual to create flashcards and other learning aides (if the course material is anemable to such a construct).
4. If you have a friend/roommate/spouse/trained monkey who can compare your answers to the manual for you, such that you don't actually read through the manual, that may be useful for certain topics.
5. You can make some good money selling it when the semester is over :)

Comment: "trained monkey" LOL. I agree with most of points. +1

Answer (score 8):

**Ignore it and write a new one.**

Looking at the solution manual is *not* useful; it only gives you *answers*.  The point of homework isn't the answers, but the struggle to find them.

Comment: If the manual only gives answers, then it isn't worth much.  However, if the manual shows how to find the answers, then it can be useful.  If you're really stuck on a problem (and have worked on it for a while), you could try just peaking at the manual to get an idea to help you get unstuck, then try to work out the details on your own (without reading the manual).

Comment: There were times during maths class in school that I checked my answer in the back of the book, realised I was wrong & reattempted the problem looking out for where I could've made a miscalculation or misunderstood something. Normally, it ended up giving me a better understanding of the problem space. It also meant that I was able to come to the right answer myself (albeit after being told that I was wrong, but not _how_ I was wrong) — without that I would've been shown the correct method anyway (when the class went over the homework), but I think I would've learned less.

Comment: Is believing this a requirement to obtain tenure? That would explain some of my former professors... If the solutions to homework exercises are not important, then why does every good university course provide students  with feedback on their homework in the form of written corrections or tutorials where a TA or professors demonstrates the solutions?

Comment: @Peter Solutions can be useful _after_ the students have already struggled to solve them, if for no other reason than to sanity-check their own grades. At least, that's why and when I give my students solutions (and advice on how to find them).

Answer (score 3):

Don't just read the solutions.  This is counterproductive.  Work the problems yourself.

However, after finishing, use the answer (not the worked solution) as a check.  It is psychologically reinforcing to have a feedback loop and know that you did it right.

If you were wrong, rework the problem.  Often the reason will have been a minor calculational mistake (in STEM).  You will usually be able to fix this on your own (without even seeing the detailed solution) just by being more careful.  If not, sometimes the format of the answer will suggest a more conceptual thing that you missed or prompt you to relook at the textbook description/examples.  This is crucial, that you fully redo even "dumb mistake" attempts.  Doing this means you won't make them again.  It's like music or sports.  If you make a mistake, do it over.  Do the entire exercise, not just the part you messed up.

In the few cases where the above is not sufficient, look at the actual worked solution to see how they do it.  But STILL.  Then put the manual down and rework the missed problem yourself.  You need to actually practice the solution process.  Not just read it.  Even though it seems hokey, it will help your learning, versus reading and saying "OK, that was the trick".

I do disagree with other answers that say you should prioritize outreach to friends, Chegg, instructors, SE, before checking the solution manual.  It is a tool for you and is extremely convenient for the disciplined drilling problem solver. I would reserve that sort of personalized outreach for when you are baffled by the written solution itself.  (Keep a written list and then see your instructor with them.)

But absolutely do use the disciplined drill, check, repeat (if wrong) method that I espouse above.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Attempt the problem on your own first.
> 2. Use outside resources and your own research to try and answer the question.

If you get stuck and can't do it on your own without a little guidance, use outside resources to read about the problem, look through other examples to get an idea of the general procedure, and get a better grasp of what the final answer should actually look like.

Personally, I don't like asking a professor for help or going to my TA's office hours unless I absolutely cannot figure out the problem on my own. So the next step might deviate from other people's opinions on how to use solutions manuals.

> 3. Use the solution manual as a quick hint as to the next step.

If you make it through some of the problem and get stuck somewhere, and you cannot find any kind of answer online or in the textbook, then use the solution manual to give you a quick hint as to how you should proceed. It's sometimes useful to see how the book author approached an integration or some weird algebraic step. If you make it to step three, then step four is the critical part of this method.

> 4. Use the hint you just took as an opportunity to further your understanding. Work through similar examples outside of the actual homework problem (in the case of a math problem), use a keyword in the solution to read about that step (in the case of a physics problem), etc. Do further research on that particular step, so that when you encounter a similar problem in the future, you will know exactly what to do.

Don't just write down the solution and move on, learn from it to deepen your understanding of the problem. After using the solutions manual and not making any progress on understanding the problem, or that particular step, then I use the following step.

> 5. Go to a professor or your TA's office hours to ask the question and get a one-on-one dialogue going about your misconception, why your attempt failed, and/or why the author of the solution did that particular step.

For a mathematics question, I typically ask them on math.stackexchange.com first, as I usually get a great response within minutes of my post. For a physics or other technical/theoretical questions, I found it best to discuss them with someone.

By going through the steps as I have listed them above, I have found that by the time I go to a professor or TA, I can explain the issue I'm having and convey it without stumbling over myself. It taught me to figure out the issue I'm having exactly and to be able to ask a very specific question, rather than going to a professor and asking some vague question about an assigned homework problem and looking for them to give me the solution.

Apologies for the novel, I hope this helps.